# Sending a document as an attachement from C# to java service using SWA (Soap with attachement)

Tags: c#, soap

I have a requirement where I have to send one SOAP attachment(PDF) to a Java WebService using C#.
Is this possible? if so, can anyone please share the code snippet?

I have another java application , that could send SWA attachement to this same Java service successfully. but Datahandler is used there. Do we have an equivalent of javax.activation.DataHandler
 in c# ?

Comment: MIME or binary?

Comment: I did not flag as dupe, since it hasn't got an accepted answer, but may help: [Adding an attachment to SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574938/adding-an-attachment-to-soap-request)

Comment: And I found this in a Forum post, but not sure if that's outdated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996944(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: MIME Type-application\PDF